# Can't get df.loc to work using dates within a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I want my loop to go through 3 dfs with the same format, and do 3 things:

1. Transform "Date" object column to datetime.
2. Use loc to filter only the dates after year 2021.
3. Set date as index.

Say I have 3 dataframes named df1, df2 and df3, they are all shaped like this:

| Index | Date | Information |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 2020-01-01 | Blablabla |
| **2** | 2021-01-01 | Blablabla |
| **3** | 2022-01-01 | Blablabla |

After running my code, I want all dfs to be shaped like this:

| Date | Information |
| --- | --- |
| **2021-01-01** | Blablabla |
| **2022-01-01** | Blablabla |

The code I'm running:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

for i in dfs:
    i['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(i['Date'])
    i = i.loc[i['Date'].dt.year >= 2021]
    i.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I can't seem to get it to work. The first part of the loop is working, it transformms to datetime, but the filter is not working neither the indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's this using a few tricks of pandas and python:

```
df1, df2, df3 = [i.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(i['Date'])).set_index('Date').loc['2021':] 
                 for i in [df1, df2, df3]]
```

1. Unpacking
2. [`pd.Dataframe.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign)
3. With datetime in index you can use [`partial string indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) with loc
4. List comprehension

Output:

```
print(f'{df1=}\n\n{df2=}\n\n{df3=}')

df1=            Index Information
Date                         
2021-01-01      2   Blablabla
2022-01-01      3   Blablabla

df2=            Index Information
Date                         
2021-01-01      2   Blablabla
2022-01-01      3   Blablabla

df3=            Index Information
Date                         
2021-01-01      2   Blablabla
2022-01-01      3   Blablabla
```

---

Fixing your for loop can be done like this:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
for i in dfs:
    i.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(i['Date']), inplace=True)
    i.query('Date >= "2021-01-01"', inplace=True)
    i.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df1
```

Answer (score 0):

step1: transform date column to 'real date'

```
d1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d1['date'])
d2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d2['date'])
d3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d3['date'])
```

step2: select >= 2021 (year) rows

```
d1_s = d1.loc[d1['date'].dt.year >= 2021,:]
d2_s = d2.loc[d2['date'].dt.year >= 2021,:]
d3_s = d2.loc[d2['date'].dt.year >= 2021,:]
```

step3: pd.concat(d1_s,d2_s,d3_s) named a new dataframe 'data_all'

```
data_all = pd.concat([d1_s,d2_s,d3_s],ignore_index=True)
```

step4:set 'date' column as index

```
data_all.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
```